# SQL dont allow duplicate records in table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make it not add duplicates?
I want to make it check by all other columns beside ID.

I want this to be invalid.

```
ID    col1    col2   col3

1    first   middle  last   


ID    col1     col2   col3

2    first   middle  last
```

I want this to be valid.

```
ID    col1    col2   col3

1    first   middle  last   


ID    col1     col2   col3

2    first    last   middle
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? To create unique composite key, for example

Comment: you should not display the duplicate records or you don't want to repeat the duplicate records ?

Comment: Your rows are not duplicated....you have two differents ID....now if you want to check col by col...

Comment: I don't want it to be checked by ID. What i want is that another record shouldn't contain same previous record.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use a **composite UNIQUE INDEX** on all three columns. See this example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    col3 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(col1, col2, col3)
);

-- expected to be valid
INSERT INTO example (ID, col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (NULL, 'first', 'middle', 'last'),
    (NULL, 'first', 'last', 'middle');

-- expected to be invalid
INSERT INTO example (ID, col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (NULL, 'first', 'middle', 'last'),
    (NULL, 'first', 'middle', 'last');
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/238d8/1)**

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding UNIQUE key over all the other columns is a possible solution.
2. Another solution would be software dependent.

   - You should first lock your table;
   - then check for the existence of that line with a where clause for all the columns;
   - insert the data if the above returns zero lines.
   - Or, if using InnoDB you might take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: The column may contain duplicate values. But i dont want the columns to contain duplicate value in this order: "first" "middle" "last".                    So "first" "last" "middle" should be valid since there is no record in that order yet.

Comment: @J0ker - I believe my solutions are resolving exactly that issue.

Comment: Getting this error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'url_id_4'    I'm 100% certain no row is in same order.

Comment: @J0ker - It seems like you already have duplicates. If you're sure you really want to remove those take a look at ALTER **IGNORE** clause when adding UNIQUE key. That would delete all the duplicates, so you might want to have a backup of your table first.

Comment: do you mean duplicate in one specific row? like col1 can't have two times same value?

Answer (score 0):

Try yo use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename
Set col1="",col2="",col3=""
```

or use

```
REPLACE INTO tablename
    Set col1="",col2="",col3=""
```

or
you can use
INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

Tell me how it works!